# Take control of my child components (md-button) in angular component code?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm trying to take control of child MdButton components using @ViewChild:

```
// In my component:
@ViewChild('add') private _add: MdButton;
@ViewChild('upload') private _upload: MdButton;
@ViewChild('del') private _del: MdButton;
...
public btnClick = (e) => { console.log(e) }
```

Now I'm trying to find out which one of them was clicked:

```
/* In template: */
<button md-button #del (click)="btnClick($event)">Delete</button>
<button md-button #change (click)="btnClick($event)">Change</button
<button md-button  #show (click)="btnClick($event)">Show</button>
```

The problem is that I can't find out which one of my button was clicked beacouse #del, #show, etc. props are disappeared after rendering and actually I don't want to add extra id attribute or something like this. Is there a way to listen my buttons inside my component class code without dealing with DOM?

**UPDATE**

I did't find nice solution and ended up with this:

```
<button md-raised-button #del (click)="_click.next('del')">Delete</button>
<button md-raised-button #add (click)="_click.next('add')">Add</button>
```

and

```
...
@ViewChild('del') private _del: MdButton;
@ViewChild('add') private _add: MdButton;

private _click = new Subject(); 
public clicked$ : Observable<any> = this._click.asObservable();
...
this.clicked$.subscribe(x=>console.log(`Button #${x} is clicked`));
```

Comment: Why don’t have have different methods for the different buttons to call?

Comment: Yea, this will work ), but what if I'll have many buttons - it will be mess with methods in my nice component...

Comment: Then won't you want those buttons to *do different things?*

Comment: I just was wondering if its possible to listen my buttons right inside the component, without adding listeners in the template.

Comment: That's not what the question says. It is unclear what that would even mean - what would you want them to *do?* Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: @Vega, yes, it is clear, I just want to avoid dealing with DOM-elements and work only with button's components instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a `HostListener` inside the component class or write a directive and set it on each button and put the `hostlistener` inside the directive. Then you can access `event.target` to check which button is clicked.

Typescript:

```
@ViewChild('show') private show;

@HostListener('document:click', ['$event', '$event.target'])
    onClick(event: MouseEvent, targetElement: HTMLElement): void {

        if (!targetElement) {
            return;
        }
        if (targetElement === this.show.nativeElement ) {
            console.log('"Просмотреть" нажата')
        }
}
```

HTML

```
<button #show>Просмотреть</button>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ousjfy?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

---

An other version, just using (click) event. This time event.currentTarget can be used:

**Typescript**:

```
@ViewChild('show') private show;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onClick(event): void {
    if (event.currentTarget === this.show.nativeElement) {
       console.log('"Просмотреть" нажата')
    }
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<button #show (click)="onClick($event)">Просмотреть</button>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hzui99?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: It is close, but still not clean, can you provide an example of how to "set a HostListener inside the component class"?

Comment: Here is a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ousjfy?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: An other solution could be this one: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hzui99?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can check the even.target like this:

```
 public btnClick = (e: Event) => { 
    const clickedBtn = <HTMLButtonElement>e.target;
        console.log(clickedBtn ) 
}
```

This way, you can track which button has been clicked.